# C# if webbrowser displays message then display a label

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to setup a loader for cs:go but I am stuck at one part of the code where I check using PHP if user exits and if the user doesn't exist then show code 2 which means that user doesn't exist. Now in C# when code 2 is displayed in the webBrowser I want it to change the IncorrectUsername from invisible to visible but for some reason it doesn't work.

Now I know that the PHP side is working perfectly.
Screenshot of Loader when user is incorrect.
[When user is incorrect code = 2][1]
Now there is supposed to be a label displayed above the first text box but its not displaying.

This is the problem

```
else if (webBrowser2.DocumentText.Contains("2"))
            {
                IncorrectUsername.Visible = true;
                username = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the PHP code

```
    <?php
$ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
$link = mysqli_connect($ini['db_host'],$ini['db_user'],$ini['db_password']);
$database = mysqli_select_db($link,$ini['db_name']);

$user = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$tables = $ini['mybb_usertable'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ". $tables ." WHERE username = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$user) ."'" ;
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Outputting the rows
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $password = $row['password'];
        $salt = $row['salt'];
        $plain_pass = $_GET['password'];
        $stored_pass = md5(md5($salt).md5($plain_pass));

        function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
        {
            if (headers_sent() === false)
            {
                header('Location: ' . $url, true, ($permanent === true) ? 301 : 302);
            }
        exit();
        }

        if($stored_pass != $row['password'])
        {
            echo "0"; // Wrong pass, user exists
        }
        else
        {
            echo "1"; // Correct pass
        }
    }
} 
else
{
    echo "2"; // User doesn't exist
}

?>

<head>
<title>Checking login info</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Is the PHP side your code? If yes then I would implement some API for external applications instead of relying on scrapping text from webpages, REST is perfect for this.

Comment: I have no clue on how I would do the API for external applications. Also why   is relying on text from web pages not a good idea?

Comment: Whenever you change the page layout your code will break. Search for examples of REST API on php, there are plenty

Comment: your API could be just pages built into your API site and have access to the same codebase as your site

Comment: I have added the php code. Which should work fine at this point im lost ;( Also screenshot of what the website displays. [Website](https://i.imgur.com/9BDji8A.png)

Comment: in the last else if, do you mean webbrowser1 or webbrowser2 ? I don't see where webbrowser2 is loading a page

Comment: If you're returning function responses and not HTML content instead of `Webbrowser` use `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the part where I messed up thanks to @derloopkat. Basically the webBrowser2 was not loaded in. So I changed from webBrowser2 to webBrowser1.

From this

```
                else if (webBrowser2.DocumentText.Contains("2"))
            {
                IncorrectUsername.Visible = true;
                username = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

To this

```
            else if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("2"))
            {
                IncorrectUsername.Visible = true;
                username = false;
            }
        }
    }
```